# How to get the event when clicking the microsoft ad in uwp

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, uwp-xaml, ads

I'm using Microsoft Advertising SDK for xaml. And my app can show the ad now. But I want to know the event when user click the ad.

None of the following event worked.

```
    <ads:AdControl x:Name="adAd" Grid.Row="3" ApplicationId="" AdUnitId=""
         Width="300" Height="250" AdRefreshed="OnAdRefreshed" 
         ErrorOccurred="OnErrorOccurred"
         Tapped="OnAdTapped" OnPointerDown="OnAdPointerDown" 
         PointerPressed="OnAdPointerPressed"/>
```

[image]

Comment: [AdControl.IsEngagedChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/apps/microsoft.advertising.winrt.ui.adcontrol.isengagedchanged.aspx) should work. And I can't see why the 3 events in your code sample "not worked".

Comment: Not work is mean when I click the ad, the event Tapped, OnPointerDown, PointerPressed does not fire. And IsEngagedChanged also not fire.

Comment: hi @Vincent  I have edited answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> None of the following event worked.

Actually, you could not use the above event directly, because it will be ignored by hyperlink click where displayed in the Ad `WebView`. 
[image]

If you want detect click event of `AdControl`, you could use some indirect way that use `VisualTreeHelper` to get the AD `WebView` and listen it's `NavigationStarting` event

```
public static T MyFindListBoxChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
{
    var MyQueue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    MyQueue.Enqueue(root);
    while (MyQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        DependencyObject current = MyQueue.Dequeue();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            var typedChild = child as T;
            if (typedChild != null)
            {
                return typedChild;
            }
            MyQueue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}


private void AdTest_AdRefreshed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ADWebView = MyFindListBoxChildOfType<WebView>(AdTest);
    ADWebView.NavigationStarting += ADWebView_NavigationStarting;
}

private void ADWebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AD clicked---------------");
}
```

In order to avoid interference from page navigation, please unsubscribe `NavigationStarting` in  `OnNavigatedFrom` override method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    ADWebView.NavigationStarting -= ADWebView_NavigationStarting;
}
```

Comment: After searching all the documents, up to now,  this is the nearly best answer, although there still exists a little problem.

Comment: Even though this is a "solution" it's an overly complicated one whereas OP was mostly looking for a single event handler. If we have to resort to this boilerplate of code to handle a single click, maybe, there are some underlying problems with UWP.