# Enable back button in NavigationView of UWP app with MvvmCross

Tags: xaml, uwp, mvvmcross, master-detail

My UWP app uses the MvvmCross framework and has a `NavigationView` with a main and a detail page, as you can see in the illustration and folder structure. Both of these pages are annotated with     `[MvxSplitViewPresentation(SplitPanePosition.Content)]` to display them on the content side. Now I want to add a working back button on the detail view, but I do not know how to enable the button and navigate back.

Info: My detail page is opened by calling `_navigationService.Navigate<DetailViewModel>();` in the `MainViewModel`.

[image]

```
├── ViewModels
│   ├── NavigatonRootsViewModel.cs
│   ├── MainViewModel.cs
│   └── DetailViewModel.cs
├── Views
│   ├── NavigationRoot.xaml
│   ├── NavigationRoot.xaml.cs
│   ├── Main.xaml
│   ├── Main.xaml.cs
│   ├── Detail.xaml
│   └── Detail.xaml.cs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NavigationView has a built-in [back button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#backwards-navigation), you could set IsBackEnabled as True to display it and subscribe the BackRequested event to control the navigate back operation in it.

.xaml:

```
<NavigationView IsBackEnabled="True" BackRequested="NavigationView_BackRequested">
    ......
<NavigationView>
```

.cs:

**Update:**

By checking the code, the page isn't loaded in the FrameContent, the NavigationView has it build-in Frame, so you can use the VisualTreeHelper to get the Frame by referring to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434881/how-to-get-the-event-when-clicking-the-microsoft-ad-in-uwp/51493909#51493909). Then use GoBack() method to navigate back.

```
private void NavigationView_BackRequested(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
{ 
    //use the MyFindListBoxChildOfType method from the link.
    var MyFrame = MyFindListBoxChildOfType<Frame>(NaviView); 
    if (MyFrame.CanGoBack) 
    {
        MyFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

Demo application: [DemoMvvmCrossNavigation](https://github.com/ammerzon/DemoMvvmCrossNavigation)

Comment: I tried that before. The back button is enabled but I get the impression that `_navigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>();` does not load the page into the Frame with the name FrameContent. The page is displayed but the back button does not work.

Comment: How did you create the MVVMCross project? I tested it and it worked well, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced?

Comment: I followed this guide [MvvmCross UWP](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/uwp/universal-windows-platform-uwp) but I can provide a demo project in a few hours.

Comment: I added the [repository](https://github.com/ammerzon/DemoMvvmCrossNavigation) to my question.